# Application Error

Tags: windows, visual-c++

Hi all I have developed a MFC Dialoag based application (server application TCP/IP communication a socket programming) on windows xp sp2.
I am getting application error message on one of the machine. but some other machine it is working fine. I am not able to fix this bug please help me .

The Error message is:

The instruction at "0x7c911948" referenced memory at "0x00000000".The memory could not be "read",
click on OK to terminate the program
click on CANCEL to debug the program

What error it is and how to fix it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your application has crashed while trying to read a NULL pointer.
Please post your call stack also. Just double check to see your memory allocation and deallocation is correct

Comment: When your application crashes from the Visual studio you can open debug->Call stack window and it will show you the series of statements that got executed before it crashed.